# What's the difference between linear space and cone?

Tags: convex-optimization

In the convex optimization domain, What's the difference between linear space and cone? thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Linear space: closed under taking sums and any real multiples. Convex cone: closed under taking sums and *nonnegative* multiples.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much.